# Selenium (Java): Which IDE to use; Eclipse or Netbeans

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java

For a new project i want to start automating tests using Selenium. I'm going with Java as the object that has to be tested is a Java application. In my company most people use either Netbeans or Eclipse.

From your experience, which IDE is more suited for Selenium webdriver: Netbeans or Eclipse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make much difference in terms of the development or scripting. But I prefer eclipse because netbeans tends to occupy a lot of memory and lower system performance. It seems to hang after a couple of hours. In that sense eclipse is more stable than netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference. Both support JUnit and TestNG as testing framework. They also support Maven and Ant as build tools. In my view, all important things to develop automated test cases with Selenium 2 / WebDriver are present.

My experience is, that NetBeans needs more time (just seconds) to start and use a little bit more memory. But seriously: it's hardly noticeable. I am sure that you find more specific comparison in the web.

It is your personal decision which appeals to you more.

Comment: Thanks. And what regarding performance/stability?

Comment: @PMartin I updated the answer. But keep in mind, that this is 
Software Quality Assurance & Testing StackExchange. This question can may be better answered at stackoverflow.

Comment: "Netbeans or Eclipse, which is best"? Err no. Best not ask that there. Incidentally it doesn't really matter if you use the same language as the software. You're interacting with it purely through the View (To pretend momentarily that something that needs selenium testing could be MVC). If you, however, personally (or as a team) prefer Java there's your reason.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans and Eclipse, you know, they are just an IDE. As far as I know, both of them do not have any official plugin(s) for Selenium, so I agree there isn't any difference. Anyway, consider your experience, I suggest Eclipse for you, because you can find plenty of blogs/web pages(etc.) to help you write test class.